# UISegmentedControl does not respond on UIControlEventValueChanged in UIToolbar

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitoolbar, uisegmentedcontrol

I created a control with some items

```
NSArray *items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"First", @"Second", @"Third",  nil];
UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:items];
```

I added target to the control

```
[segmentedControl addTarget:self
                     action:@selector(controlTapped:)
           forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Than i added my segmented control to the toolbar

```
[toolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:
                          [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:segmentedControl]autorelease]]];
```

As a result segmentedControl doesn't respond on user tap.

Here is the empty empty method

```
-(void) controlTapped:(id)sender {
```

}

Comment: It might be helpful if you could write down your `controlTapped:` method too!

Comment: I added the method, but the it is empty. This code works when i add segmented Control to a navigation bar, but in the tool bar it doen't.

Comment: It is declared, and it has some ,code which does not invoke, for example :the code is NSLog(@"..."). The problem is not in the method,because it works in the navigationbar. I think segmented control doesn't want to be as a custom view of uibarbuttonitem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a similar question that has been [asked and answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1989483/uisegmentedcontrol-uitoolbar-and-uinavigationitem) before(so it is possible to add `UISegmentedControl` to toolbar) but I think the problem here is that you've used the wrong method to set the items. I went through the [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIToolbar_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIToolbar) and couldn't find a `setItems:` method. Use [`setItems:animated:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIToolbar_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIToolbar) instead.

**EDIT-** I checked this by making a sample project and it worked fine. I tried with your code and with my suggestions and it worked both ways! Use a break-point to be sure that the control goes(or doesn't go) into the `controlTapped:` method.

Comment: I changed setItems to setItems:animated , but nothing new happend. I still see the segment control, but can't change selected value :(

Comment: Really thanks) I made an idiot mistake, set the wrong frame to the segmented view and that caused the reason not to respond on tapping.

Comment: Not to worry...such mistakes happen all the time